# jcrop zoom, rotate, crop and resize later

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jcrop

http://hollywoodlacewigs.netsmartz.us/
I am working on above project. 
user upload pic form 'upload' button and then 'select area' and then click 'mix' button.
this will show the cropped area onto other image. 
click email link will compose two images.

But before that I want to let user 'rotate', 'zoom in/out' image before cropping the image.

am using jcrop, jquery ui draggable

here's the script :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#UploadForm').change('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#SubmitButton').attr('disabled', ''); // disable upload button
        $('#left-pic').hide();
        $('#output').show();
        //show uploading message
        $("#output").html('<img style="margin:45px 0px 0px 35px; " src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Please Wait"/>');
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            target: '#output',
            success:  afterSuccess //call function after success
        });
    });


}); 

function afterSuccess(){ 
    $('#UploadForm').resetForm();  // reset form
    $('#SubmitButton').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable submit button
    $('#cropbox').Jcrop({       
        aspectRatio: 1,
        onSelect: updateCoords,
        bgOpacity: 0.5,
        bgColor: 'white',
        addClass: 'jcrop-dark',
        setSelect: [ 34, 50, 134, 155 ]
    });     
}

function updateCoords(c){
    $('#x').val(c.x);
    $('#y').val(c.y);
    $('#w').val(c.w);
    $('#h').val(c.h);
}

function checkCoords(){
    if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
    alert('Please select a crop region then press submit.');
    return false;
}

$(function() {
    $('#draggable3').draggable({
        containment: $('#draggable3').parent(),
        cursor: "move", cursorAt: { top: 56, left: 56 },
         drag: function(event, ui) {
            // Show the current dragged position of image
            var currentPos = $(this).position();
            // $("#xpos").text("CURRENT: \nLeft: " + (currentPos.left-580) + "\nTop: " + (currentPos.top-82));
            $('#x3').val(currentPos.left-580);
            $('#y3').val(currentPos.top-82);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.cropzoom.com.ar/demo/, I used and like it. 
In IE exists one bug - fix is described on [Draggable element in VML get stuck when size change (height, width) in IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422937)
(I want to add answer in comment, but don't have permission)

Comment: I am sorry to add that it must work on android and ios as well.

Comment: Yes, only jcrop so far is the only one which works on all browsers and platforms.

Comment: So need to customize jcrop as much as can to suite the needs :)

Comment: Any sort of help is much appreciated !

Comment: The link doesn't work. Seems the site is down, is there any other place?